# How can I cast an item in my xml to a xdmp:function?

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I can't seem to get this element in my xml to be an `xdmp:function`.

Here is the xml:

```
<xml xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <function xsi:type="xdmp:function" xmlns:xdmp="http://marklogic.com/xdmp">xdmp:function(xs:QName("fn:empty"))</function>
</xml>
```

As you can see I've tried to put the type in the xml that didnt work.

I've tried to use `cast as`  that also didnt work. I've tried wrapping the element in `xdmp:function` and that also doesnt work.

I'm able to put the function into a map and get it out. like this:

```
let $function := xdmp:function(xs:QName("fn:empty"))
let $xml :=
<xml xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <function xsi:type="xdmp:function" xmlns:xdmp="http://marklogic.com/xdmp">{$function}</function>
</xml>
let $map := map:map()
let $put := map:put($map, 'function', $function)
let $mapFunction := map:get($map, 'function')
let $applyMapFunction := xdmp:apply($mapFunction, "something")
(:
  let $xmlFunction :=  $xml/function
  let $applyXmlFunction := xdmp:apply($xmlFunction, "something")
:)
return $xml

<xml xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <function xsi:type="xdmp:function" xmlns:xdmp="http://marklogic.com/xdmp">xdmp:function(xs:QName("fn:empty"))</function>
</xml>
```

However I dont want to have to make a map just to cover the item into a xdmp:function.

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: why would you want to serialize such function signatures?

Comment: I was serializing a different function but I changed it to that one for SO. I want to be able to save a function to get called at a later time. I'm going to use apply on it and you have to use xdmp:function when call apply so I that I'd save sometime by saving it that format. I'm now just saving the parts of of xdmp:function and putting them together to apply the function.

Comment: Serializing arguments, and composing the xdmp:function call that way is much safer against code injection, and doesn't require special privs. Keep in mind you may need to reference a module path as well..

Comment: Thats when I ended up doing. I was want to save the already composed xdmp:function to use later and was hoping that it would come back usable but it doesn't seem to come back as a function and thats why it needs to be eval, which makes it not as safe. Its just odd that the value of xdmp:function acts is a xdmp:function call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to `eval` the "serialized" function to extract it from a string or XML context:

```
xdmp:eval($xml/function/fn:string())
```

Alternately, you can use [`xdmp:value`](http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:value), which is a more limited `eval` function (it uses the same execution context) and therefore protects against some types of code injection:

```
xdmp:value($xml/function/fn:string())
```

Comment: map:map(document{$map}/*) gives a parse error as well, I think eval and value are indeed the only options.

Comment: Thank @joemfb for the answer. I was hoping i wouldnt have to use eval, value would be better. I guess xdmp:function is just different because its value is a function.